# Insertion efficiency of a large amount of data with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, sql-insert

I have a program that I use to read CSV file and insert the data into a database. I am having trouble with it because it needs to able to insert big records ( up to 10,000 rows ) of data at a time. At first I had it looping through and inserting each record one at a time. That is slow because it calls an insert function 10,000 times... Next I tried to group it together so it inserted 50 rows at a time. I figured this way it would have to connect to the database less, but it is still too slow. What is an efficient way to insert many rows of a CSV file into a database? Also, I have to edit some data(such as add a 1 to a username if two are the same) before it goes into the database.

Comment: Use the [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) command

Comment: @MikeW you took the words out my keyboard. The first line of the docs is "The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed.". If you make it an answer I'll upvote you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the LOAD DATA INFILE command will work because I have to edit some data before it goes into the database. Thanks for the suggestion, but any more ideas?

Comment: @user1423793 What editing needs to be done? LOAD DATA can reformat and process data while it loads if you set up the command properly. Perhaps if you posted more information in your question we could be a little more focussed.

Comment: I have to change things such as add a 1 to a username if two are the same, or generate a username or password if none are provided.

Comment: Try querying a list of all user ids and store them to an array, then process the list line-by-line to make any fixes you need. Instead of generating a query, generate a new csv to upload using LOAD DATA.

Answer (score 1):

For a text file you can use the [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) command which is designed to do exactly this. It'll handle CSV files by default, but has extensive options for handling other text formats, including re-ordering columns, ignoring input rows, and reformatting data as it loads.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up using the fputcsv to put the data I changed into a new CSV file, then I used the LOAD DATA INFILE command to put the data from the new csv file into the table. This changed it from timing out at 120 secs for 1000 entries, to taking about 10 seconds to do 10,000 entries. Thank you to everyone that replied.

Answer (score 0):

I have this crazy idea: Could you run multiple parallels scripts, each one takes care of a bunch of rows from your CSV.

Some thing like this:

```
<?php

// this tells linux to run the import.php in background,
// and releases your caller script.
//
// do this several times, and you could increase the overal time
$cmd = "nohup php import.php [start] [end] & &>/dev/null";
exec($cmd);
```

Also, have you tried to increase these limit of 50 bulk inserts to 100 or 500 for example?

Comment: Yes I tried changing the limit of 50 bulk inserts up to 1000, but it times out after 120 seconds. Running parallel scripts would take up as much memory or more as what I am already doing.