# Inserting large CSV with multiple SQL calls too slow

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, sql-insert

At my company, I use a program read CSV files and insert the data into a database. I am having trouble with it because it needs to able to insert a large amount of data ( up to 10,000 rows ) of a time. At first I had it looping through and inserting each record one at a time. That is slow because it calls an insert function 10,000 times... Next I tried to group it together so it inserted 50 rows at a time by concatenating the SQL call. I have tried grouping the SQL calls into up to 1,000 rows at a time, but it is still too slow.

Another thing that I have to do is change data. The client gives a spreadsheet with a data such as their username and password, but sometimes the usernames are the same, so I change them by adding a number at the end. i.e. JoDoe, JoDoe1. Sometimes the case is that there is no password or username, so I have to generate one. The reason I bring this up is that I read that using LOAD DATA INFILE reads a file really fast and puts it into a table, but I need to edit it before going into the table.

It will time out after 120 seconds, and what doesn't get finished in that time is inserted as all 0's. I need to speed it up so it doesn't take as long. I do NOT want to change the time limit because it is a company thing. What is an efficient way to insert many rows of a CSV file into a database?

Comment: i would expect 10000 to take more than 120 seconds if your editing. is the issue the time out (easy to fix) or does it need to take less time?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112192/insertion-efficiency-of-a-large-amount-of-data-with-sql#comment26518636_18112192)

Comment: One method is to use PHP to transform the CSV (i.e. do your editing) and write it to another file. Use this newly created file to do `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Another method is to use a tool like SSIS. Yet another is to use a prepared statement call it 10K times.

Comment: look into `set_time_limit(0)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php, and `ingnore_user_abort(true)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: Have you tried using `extended inserts`? Also, you can write the sql to a file and then call `load data infile` on the newly generated file. But if you use the `extended inserts` that should solve most of your issues. (IE no SQL call(s) inside the loop).

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE can perform numerous preprocessing operations as it loads. That might be enough. If not, run a PHP script to process from one CSV file to another, temporary, CSV file, editing as you go. The use `LOAD DATA INFILE` on that.

Comment: its possible you cant speed it up, i would put this in to the background and let it run as long as it needs to. And please don't create a new account and ask the same question again.

Comment: @MikeW This worked wonderfully. I changed the data and put it into another CSV file with fputcsv, then used LOAD DATA INFILE, and deleted the CSV file. WOW 10,000 took less than 2 seconds! If you put this as the answer, I will select it and up-vote it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` can perform numerous preprocessing operations as it loads the data. That might be enough. If not, run a PHP script to process from one CSV file to another, temporary, CSV file, editing as you go. Then use `LOAD DATA INFILE` on the newly created file.